# Can other wizards inside Hogwarts see the door of the Room of Requirement when someone is entering?

Tags: harry-potter

If someone were to enter the Room of Requirement, do other wizards see them enter the Room and do they see the door?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

There are various instances in the books where Harry describes people entering/leaving the Room of Requirement, which he couldn't do if he did not see them.

Here is a quote about the DA hiding in the room:

> “It’s a proper hideout, as long as one of us stays in here, they can’t get at us, the door won’t open."

Which indicates that the door is available, but that it won't open.

Also there is:

> "...the door materialized on their third run past.
>   The furor of the battle died the moment they crossed the threshold
>   and closed the door behind them: All was silent."

Here the door appears for all three of them, and they enter it together, which wouldn't be possible if the Room made it so that people entering were invisible to others, or if it made the door invisible.

Finally, from *Order of the Phoenix*:

> There was a gentle knock on the door. Harry looked round. Ginny, Neville, Lavender, Parvati and Dean had arrived.

At that point in the book, Harry had not told anyone about the room or how to get in, only its location. Meaning that the door was available for them to see and knock on without knowing.

Granted the Room is highly "customizable" as Neville found out in *The Deathly Hallows*, so if someone specifically requested that the door was invisible, and that they shouldn't be seen entering, I feel like the Room could do this. However it is **not** a persistent quality of the Room, as shown by canon evidence.

Comment: Do you have specific cases (at lease approx circumstances if not quotes)?

Comment: @DVK Sure thing.